# how to prompt user to remove multiple columns using the readline() in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a code that allows the user to decide how many columns to remove from a table in R. The steps I am trying to perform are as follows:

1) print the column headers of the table
2) ask the user if they want to remove any columns. If the answer is yes, proceed to remove columns. This is in a loop, in case the user wants to remove multiple columns.
3) once the user is done removing columns, I want the modified table (with unwanted columns removed) to be returned so that it can be used later in script.
4) if the user does not want to remove any columns at all, they can just proceed, and the table is returned with no columns missing.

I am having 2 major issues/questions with my code as I currently have it:

1) the loop only works once (only one column is removed). the loop does work (it keeps prompting me if I keep answering "Y"), however in the end, the returned object only has 1 column removed (the first column I removed when the loop began). I tried to find if there is a way to have the user write in multiple inputs using readline, however the answers I found did not really help me.

2) If I don't want to remove any columns, and I enter "no" the first time I'm prompted for input, something very strange happens where what is returned is a table with the first column is removed.

I am still a newbie at coding, and I realize this may not be the best way to do what I want to do. I appreciate any advice/feedback!

```
my_data<-read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
print(names(my_data)
for (column in my_data) {
    remove_columns<-readline("Would you like to remove any columns? \n")
    if(remove_columns=="Y" || remove_columns=="y") {
        my_data_new<-my_data[,-!names(my_data) %in% c(readline("Which columns would you like to remove? \n"))]

    } else {
        return(my_data_new)
    }}
```

Comment: `if(tolower(remove_columns) == "y")` to save on typing, and repetition. Also, `-!...` is dangerous and can produce unintended results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for a `while` loop

```
my_data <- read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
print(names(my_data)

while (TRUE) {
    remove_columns <- readline("Would you like to remove any columns? \n")

    if (remove_columns == "Y" || remove_columns == "y") {
        my_data <- my_data[,-!names(my_data) %in% c(readline("Which columns would you like to remove? \n"))]
    } else {
       break
    }
}
```

Comment: FANTASTIC!! This is such a simple solution and it works great! I've spent all day trying to figure this out, I should have just posted my question earlier and saved myself the headache. THANK YOU Evan_K!